# Copy CSV with comma decimal separator into SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm learning to build data pipelines using DataFactory v2. I'm trying to copy a flat file from BLOB storage to Azure SQL Server.
The numeric values are loaded incorrectly, ignoring the comma.
.

I uploaded a flat file (semicolon separated values, comma as the decimal separator) to the BLOB storage and tried a first simple copy BLOB to BLOB and it works fine.
Then I set up an SQL Server and create a Table matching the structure of the flat file. All field are string except two witch are `float` Latitude and Longitude. 
I set up the source and sink and I mapped the field name and datatype correctly (I tried both Decimal and Double for the numeric values).

The pipeline runs fine but when I inspect the result on the DB I notice that the numeric values are written ignoring the comma.
How can I handle this? I looked extensively but found nothing (except modifying the original flat file before uploading it to the BLOB)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the culture? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services#dataset-structure

Comment: @JasonP YES! thank you. I had to modify manually Datasets JSON adding the attribute culture to both variables. I wonder if there is a smarter way to do it. Maybe on the Dataset level or some system variable to modify. Do you know?